# Get notified when ref.current changes in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

Is there a way to get notified when ref.current changes in React ? Like the code below.

```
const ref = useRef(0);

// pseudo code
ref.addCallback((newValue)=> {
  // notified
});

ref.current = 1; // triggers the notification.
```

Comment: is there any reason for not to use `useState` & `useEffect` ?

Comment: may want to consider using a callback ref https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node if it's related to dom. If it's not then its better to use useState

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) hook like so:

```
const onChange = useCallback(value => {
   if(value) {
      // do whatever you want
   }
}, []);
```

And pass the function to the ref `ref` prop:

```
<div ref={onChange}></div>
```

Note that this does not trigger rerendes yet. You would need to set `value` to a state.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library like [Observable Slim](https://github.com/ElliotNB/observable-slim)

Here is an example of how you would use it:

```js
ObservableSlim.create(ref.current, true, function(changes) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(changes));
});
```